# PyQt and Netgraph Interactive Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, interactive, netgraph

I have an application with PyQt and I would like to add the Netgraph graphs interactiviness to my application.

However, I am not being able to click the vertex and edges of the graph.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import sys

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from netgraph import InteractiveGraph

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import networkx as nx

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        g = nx.house_x_graph()

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

        plot_instance = InteractiveGraph(g)

        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(sc, self)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(sc)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.show()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

And here is an example with the behavior I want:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from netgraph import EditableGraph

g = nx.house_x_graph()


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

plot_instance = EditableGraph(g)

plt.show()
```

Any ideas how I can make Netgraph interactiviness work along with PyQt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors but the most important are:

- You must use the same figure from the canvas, and not create a new one using pyplot.
- You have to pass the Axes as an argument to InteractiveGraph so that it uses the already created figure.
- Save the instance of InteractiveGraph as an attribute of the class.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")


from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from netgraph import InteractiveGraph

import networkx as nx


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi))
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        graph = nx.house_x_graph()
        self.plot_instance = InteractiveGraph(graph, ax=self.ax)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
But I have a question. I tried to change the InteractiveGraph to EditableGraph, and that did not work. 
Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @LavíniaBeghini Which means it doesn't work, it works fine for me. When we say it does not work, you must give more details since it can mean thousands of things. If you want more detail check the source code of both libraries and analyze what the differences are . Bye.

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear. EditableGraph allows to add a new vertex and delete a vertex, for example. To add a new vertex, with nothing selected click with a '+' anywhere on the screen. If InteractiveGraph is replaced by EditableGraph without Qt, you are able to see that behavior. You can also check it [here](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph#interactivity). However, making the same changes at the Qt example is not working.